# How to run rviz2 with own settings in .rviz from launch file which refers to my my package via arguments = ["-d", "$(find my_package)/rviz/my.rviz"]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! As in question. How to run `rviz2` with my own settings saved in `.rviz` from the launch file which refers to `my_package` by name? I can add that when I refer to the .rviz file using its absolute path, it works.

The following launches rviz2 but without own settings:

```
     my_rviz2 = Node(package = "rviz2", 
                    executable = "rviz2",
                    arguments = ["-d", "$(find my_package)/rviz/my.rviz"]
                    )


    ld = LaunchDescription()

    ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time_argument)
    ld.add_action(declare_params_file_cmd)
    ld.add_action(log_param_change)
    ld.add_action(my_rviz2)
    
    return ld
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386349/how-to-run-rviz2-with-own-settings-in-.rviz-from-launch-file-which-refers-to-my-my-package-via-arguments-=-%5B%22-d%22,-%22$(find-my_package)/rviz/my.rviz%22%5D/) by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2021-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've done something like:

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import launch
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    my_package_dir = get_package_share_directory('my_package')
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        Node(package='rviz2',
             executable='rviz2',
             arguments=['-d', os.path.join(my_package_dir, 'rviz', 'my.rviz')])
    ])
```

The key here is the `get_package_share_directory` function.

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1